# Spark replace \" with "" - regexp_replace

Tags: java, apache-spark

Trying to replace \n with empty and \" with "". But \" gets replaced with \"\" in the string.

```
String : "blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" "
Expected o/p: "blockquote class=""twitter-tweet"" "
Actual o/p : "blockquote class=\"\"twitter-tweet\"\" "


flattenedDataSet = flattenedDataSet.withColumn(col, functions.regexp_replace(functions.regexp_replace(flattenedDataSet.col(col),"\\\"","\"\""), "\n", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is missing one "\\":

```
String str = "blockquote class=\\\"twitter-tweet\\\" ";
String expected = "blockquote class=\"\"twitter-tweet\"\" ";
System.out.println("String : " + str);
System.out.println("Expected o/p: " + expected);
System.out.println("Actual   o/p: " + str.replaceAll("\\\\\"","\"\"").replaceAll( "\n", ""));
```

Output:

```
String : blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" 
Expected o/p: blockquote class=""twitter-tweet"" 
Actual   o/p: blockquote class=""twitter-tweet""
```

Comment: Trying to replace with  Apache spark regexp_replace. str.replaceAll wouldn't work as expected in my case.   functions.regexp_replace(flattenedDataSet.col(col),"\\\"","\"\"") . Also any text instead of "\"\"" works fine. Just escape character is not working as intended.